# Do something if df does not contain specific column name

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do an `if else` operation based on non-existence of a specific column name in the `df`.

```
if a_specific_column_is_NOT_in_the_df:
   print('not ok')
else:
   print('ok')
```

With the following code I can do the reverse of my task.

```
if [col for col in df.columns if 'A' in col]:
    print('ok')
else:
    print('not ok')
```

My task is to print `not ok` if df does **not** contain column names A and to print ```ok`` if otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see any question

Comment: I guess what you want is "if 'column_name' in df. columns: ..."

Comment: I want "if 'column_name' NOT in df. columns:

Answer (score 1):

do it just by adding Not in front of list

```
 if not [col for col in df.columns if 'A' in col]:
        print('not ok')
 else:
        print('ok')
```

for instance this one will result not ok:

```
if not [col for col in ['B','C'] if 'A' in col]:
    print('not ok')
else:
    print('ok')
```

Comment: Using answer from @Sina, this shorter script works:
```if 'A' not in df.columns:```

Comment: no code from @sina is not working in this condition: 'A' in ['AX', 'BX', 'CX']